# I'm getting "The file you tried to play is an empty file" when opening some mkv's

Tags: video, mkv

So I downloaded a show with mkv files and almost all play except 2. I receive that error message when attempting to open them even though the files match the correct size as stated by the uploader and were downloaded entirely. In Properties for those files, under Audio/Video, everything is listed as "Unknown" or "N/A".

I have restricted extras installed already.

Could this simply be an issue with the uploader having corrupt files? He stated they are fine for him.

Comment: Try playing the two with VLC. It can play literally almost any video format that exists, so it might play them.

Comment: I should have mentioned above that I tried VLC as well. When I open the file with it, it just does nothing. No error message or anything. It's strange.

Comment: If you got the file from a friend or someone you know, you could have them take the md5sum of the file, and see if it is the same as your md5sum. If it is different, then the file has changed, and try re-receiving the file